# Content appears beneath div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div and when you hover over it, an identical div will appear right next to it. In this hover div I want to give more information about the div that you hovered.

My problem is; Content appears underneath the div but with the styling (i.e. border radius & background color).

My HTML:

The div you need to hover.

```
    <div id="tankinfo"><p class="info">Content what appears beneath the div.</p></div>
```

My CSS:

```
.links{
    float: left;
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 135px;
    color: white;
}
.tank{
    height: 175px;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #CECECE;
    border-radius: 5px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 75px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
#tankinfo{
    height: auto;
    width: 250px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 75px;
    background-color: #CECECE;
    margin-left: 275px;
    color: white;
}
p.info{
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    color: white;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: 300;
    top: -5%;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

An image of the situation right now;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeItn.jpg

EDIT:
An image of the situation with display: inline-block;
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXKwP.jpg

Comment: Both you div and your p tag have default display styling (block) so sit on their own line, you either need to float them, display: inline-block or use positioning on the P tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a problem, thats how div's work, they are block level elements so they will drop to another line.

You'd need `display:inline-block;` in your css to have them next to each other

Comment: It actually helped, thanks. Only problem i've got now is that the css adds extra margin on the top somehow. Do i need to float them?